# Scrapy stopping conditions

Tags: scrapy

Illustrative scenario: A Scrapy spider is built to scrape restaurant menus from a `start_urls` list of various restaurant websites. Once the menu is found for each restaurant, it is no longer necessary to continue crawling that particular restaurant website. The spider should (ideally) abort the queue for that `start_url` and move on to the next restaurant.

Is there a way to stop Scrapy from crawling the remainder of its request queue *per start_url* once a stopping condition is satisfied? I don't think that a CloseSpider exception is appropriate since I don't want to stop the entire spider, just the queue of the current `start_url`, and then move on to the next `start_url`.

Comment: There is no such option. Nevertheless, you can keep a queue of requests per start url and continue yielding the requests until you find the menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont't use scrapy rules.
All what you need:

```
start_urls = [
        'http://url1.com', 'http://url2.com', ...
    ]

def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield Request(url, self.parse_url)

def parse_url(self, response):
        hxs = Selector(response)
        item = YourItem()
        # process data 
        return item
```

And don't forget add all domains to `allowed_domains` list.